# Left join mysql problems

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

Hello I have 2 tables that look like this,

[image]

What I wanting to is get the category and the section title of the category, mySQL looks like this,

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_id`, 
       `categories`.`category_title`, 
       `categories`.`category_created`, 
       `section`.`section_id`, 
       `section`.`section_title`, 
       `categories`.`parent_section` 
 FROM (`categories`) 
 LEFT JOIN `section` 
 ON `section`.`section_id` = `categories`.`category_id`
```

However all I am getting back is a list of the categories and the sections, not a list of the categories and their **parent** section. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I bet you meant to JOIN ON `section`.`section_id` = `categories`.`parent_section_id`

Comment: ah crap! knew it would be something stupid!

Comment: What is parent_section, a self reference? Is `categories` a tree? Is your requirement to fetch the parent in that case?

Comment: Shouldn't you be joining on `categories.parent_section` then? And why does this need to be a left join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the parent section, then your join condition should be on that column:

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_id`, 
       `categories`.`category_title`, 
       `categories`.`category_created`, 
       `section`.`section_id`, 
       `section`.`section_title`, 
       `categories`.`parent_section` 
 FROM (`categories`) 
 LEFT JOIN `section` 
 ON `section`.`section_id` = `categories`.`parent_section`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
SELECT `categories`.`category_id`, 
       `categories`.`category_title`, 
       `categories`.`category_created`, 
       `section`.`section_id`, 
       `section`.`section_title`, 
       `categories`.`parent_section` 
 FROM (`categories`) 
 LEFT JOIN `section` 
 ON `section`.`section_id` = `categories`.`parent_section`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
... 
LEFT JOIN section S ON S.section_id = categories.parent_section;
```